# What is this piece of classical music heard on the UK Channel BBC 2, on the Great Australian Railway Journeys series?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Can anyone help with identifying [this piece](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AtpX87bFfUXTjwvXoHqFty4w61_gjflG/view?usp=drivesdk) of classical music, please?

It was on Great Australian Railway Journeys series 1 episode 5 (Kuranda to Townsville) last Saturday (Nov 23), on the UK Channel BBC 2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be from the London composer [Jon Wygens](https://www.jonwygens.com/recording-in-prague) who has done a lot of work for ITV, BBC, etc.

It's typical for BBC shows to commission their own music for their series (i.e. *Blue Planet*, *Planet Earth*).

BBC's [Radiophonic Workshop](https://www.bbc.com/historyofthebbc/anniversaries/april/bbc-radiophonic-workshop) being the most obvious in-house example, I suppose [cue: [Dr. Who theme]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USijQAth1Tc)...